# What's the proof that sum of all projection operators for orthonormal basis gives us identity operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

\begin{align}
\ I = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ {\sum_{i} |i{\rangle}}{{\langle}i|}=I
\end{align}

$I$ is identity operator, while the $|i{\rangle}$ is the orthonormal basis. How can I prove this sum?

Answer (score 3):

Act with your sum of projection operators on an arbitrary state psi. Use completeness to expand psi into a sum of basis vectors. Use orthonormality to simplify the sum (with $\langle n |m\rangle=\delta_{ij} $). Simplify. The sum you're left with is the original vector psi. By the arbitrariness of the initial vector, the operator must be the identity matrix.

Comment: Ah, the same answer. Sorry, shall I delete?

Comment: @TylerHG I don't care either way. No biggie!

Answer (score 3):

Take the expansion of an arbitrary vector in an orthonormal basis like so
$$ |\alpha\rangle = \sum |i\rangle\langle i |\alpha\rangle=\left(\sum |i\rangle\langle i |\right)|\alpha\rangle$$

But, this is true for any $|\alpha\rangle$, so the sum over projections must be the identity operator.